# JIRA Worklog API not working

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to log work in JIRA using the Web API :-

My data is:

```
var post = {};
post.commment  = "Test";
post.timeSpent = "6h";
```

My Ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: lv_url,
    type : 'POST',
    data : post,
    headers: { 
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : 'json',
    xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
           },
    async: false,
    success : function(data) {

    }
});
```

https://jiraserver.co/rest/api/2/issue/SOCOMPT-1575/worklog

"GET" call is working fine but when i try to POST i get the error:-

1) OPTIONS https://jiraserver.co/rest/api/2/issue/SOCOMPT-1575/worklog 500 (Internal Server Error)
 2) XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://jiraserver.co/rest/api/2/issue/SOCOMPT-1575/worklog. Invalid HTTP status code 500

These are the 2 errors is get.

Please Help Guys i really need to get this working.

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh.

Answer (score 1):

I was also strugging on this one as I kept getting HTTP 500 when trying to post to the worklog endpoint.

- if you are able check the jira server logs (under logs/catalina.out)
- jira seems to be very picky with the iso8601 date format

Try setting also the "started" timestamp in your payload as I believe this is required (for the API like the web UI) even if the [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e345) is not really clear on that.

```
post.started = '2015-02-25T14:01:30.000-0500';
```